# c++ finding lowest in 2d arrays diagonal

Tags: c++, arrays

Need to find lowest value in arrays diagonal, came up with this code but doesn't really work..

```
int min = mas[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (mas[i][j] < min) min = mas[i][j];
  }
}
cout << "min = " << min << endl;
cout << endl;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You search for all i = 0 ... n with for all j = 0 ... m. So, you get the overall minimum (of the complete 2d array). How about `for (int i = 0; i < std::min(n, m); ++i) if (min > mas[i][i]) min = mas[i][i];`? Or did I misunderstood "diagonal"?

Comment: May be, you had realized this with better code formatting... ;-)

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't really work".

Comment: The problem in your code, is you are "looking at" and comparing each element. Quick fix in your code (without copy pasting other answers) is `if (i == j && mas[i][j] < min)`, because you want to find minimum only in diagonal. Of course this does not work, if you want to find min in a diagonal from upper right to bottom left corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume there's a 2D array called `mas` whose extents are `n` and `m`. This is how to find the minimal element of the diagonal:

```
int minimal = mas[0][0];
for(unsigned int i = 1; i < std::min(n, m); ++i) {
    if(mas[i][i] < minimal) {
        minimal = mas[i][i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the diagonal elements, store them in a container and use the [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to obtain the smallest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int mas[5][5] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
                      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
                      { 4, 3, 2, 1, 45 }, 
                      { 5, 3, 8, 9, 66 }, 
                      { 4, 3, 2, 1, 45 } };
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        v.push_back(mas[i][5 - i - 1]);
    }
    auto min = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "The smallest element on the diagonal is: " << min;
}
```

The diagonal formula you are searching for is `mas[i][n - i - 1]` for one diagonal and `mas[i][i]` for the other.
If you insist on raw arrays use:

```
int min = mas[0][n - 0 - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((mas[i][n - i - 1]) < min){
        min = mas[i][n - i - 1];
    }
}
```

for one diagonal and the:

```
int min = mas[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((mas[i][i]) < min){
        min = mas[i][n - i - 1];
    }
}
```

for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below 3x3 array as an example:

```
   0 1 2 
0| 7 3 2 |
1| 4 6 5 |
2| 1 9 8 |
```

As you can see the coordinates of diagonal elements are (0,0), (1,1) and (2,2).

Using this fact we can just use two for loops to iterate over the 2D array to only find the minimum value for when the `x` and `y` coordinate equal each other:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int height = 3;
  int width = 3;

  int arr[height][width] =
  {
    {7,3,2},
    {4,6,5},
    {1,9,8}
  };

  cout << "The 2D array looks like this: " << endl;
  int min = arr[0][0];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++ ) {
      cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
      if(i==j and min > arr[i][j]) {
        min = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << "The minimum value of the diagonal of the 2D array is: " << min << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
The 2D array looks like this: 
7 3 2 
4 6 5 
1 9 8 
The minimum value of the diagonal of the 2D array is: 6
```